# How find this vmatrix of this $a_{n}=\frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!}$

Tags: matrices

find this value 
$$B_{n\times n}=\begin{vmatrix}
a_{1}&a_{0}&\cdots&\cdots&0\\
a_{2}&\cdots&&\cdots&\cdots\\
\cdots&\cdots&&\cdots&\cdots\\
a_{n-1}&&\cdots&a_{1}&a_{0}\\
a_{n}&a_{n-1}&\cdots&a_{2}&a_{1}
\end{vmatrix}$$
where 
$$a_{0}=1,a_{n}=\dfrac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!}(n\ge 1)$$
Thank you everyone, Later I post my idea.

Comment: What's to the right of $a_0$ in the first line? What about the entry $b_{2n}$? There's an equal missing to the right of $B_{n\times n}$.

Comment: yes,This is $n\times n$ martix

Comment: Git's question was not yes or no. I also don't understand the pattern.

Comment: why?where are don't understand?

Comment: Exactly what Git said two days ago. What is to the right of $a_0$ on the first line? (entry 1, 3 in your matrix) WHat about $b_{2n}$ ?

Comment: I would guess the third column looks like $0, a_0, a_1, ...$ and in subsequent columns this is shifted down. And I suppose the determinant is being asked.

Comment: I think this is a kind of Toeplitz matrix:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toeplitz_matrix

Comment: Your title is confusing. Do you mean "find the determinant"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to derive a recurrence. What you have here is a [Toeplitz](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ToeplitzMatrix.html)-[Hessenberg](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HessenbergMatrix.html) matrix. Moreover, $a_0 = 1$, so it has the special form

$$
\left[\begin{matrix}
a_1&1&0&\cdots&0\\
a_2&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots&\vdots\\
\vdots&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots&0\\
a_{n-1}&\ddots&\ddots&a_1&1\\
a_{n}&a_{n-1}&\cdots&a_2&a_1
\end{matrix}\right]
$$

for which Inselberg [1] gives the elegant recurrence:

$$\sum_{i=0}^n (-1)^{n-1} a_i B_{(n-i)\times(n-i)} = 0$$

(For a less elegant form, see the revision history for my derivation...)

Although he doesn't state it, I believe this only holds for $n > 0$, as otherwise we could trivially prove that if all of the $a_i$ are non-zero then all of the $B_{i\times i}$ are zero.

He also provides a link to generating functions: if the $a_i$ have generating function $f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n$ then $\frac 1{f(z)} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n B_{n\times n}z^n$. I don't know why he doesn't fix the signs by stating instead that $g(z) = \frac 1{f(-z)} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty B_{n\times n}z^n$

Unfortunately I don't have Maple to try using convert/ratpoly to guess a generating function for your specific $a_i$. However, I can compute some values:

$B_{2\times 2} = -\frac{1}{8};\;
B_{3\times 3} = \frac{1}{16}; \; 
B_{4\times 4} = -\frac{5}{128}; \; 
B_{5\times 5} = \frac{7}{256}; \; 
B_{6\times 6} = -\frac{21}{1024}; \; 
B_{7\times 7} = \frac{33}{2048}; \; 
B_{8\times 8} = -\frac{429}{32768}; \; 
B_{9\times 9} = \frac{715}{65536}; \; 
B_{10\times 10} = -\frac{2431}{262144}
$

OEIS turns up [two matches](http://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C1%2C5%2C7%2C21%2C33%2C429%2C715%2C2431) for the unsigned numerators, with links to double-factorials and Catalan numbers. The comments there lead me to speculate that a generating function for (signed) $B_{n\times n}$ is $g(z) = \frac 1{1+\sqrt{1+z}}$ and that $$ B_{n \times n} = \frac{(-1)^{n-1} (2n-3)!!}{n! \; 2^n} = \frac{(-1)^{n-1} (2n-3)!!}{(2n)!!} = \frac{(-1)^{n-1} a_n}{2n-1} $$

There may be a combinatorial proof, but I'm really a compsci and hence I automatically look for inductive proofs.

We can consider $B_{0\times 0}$ to be $1$ (the determinant of an empty matrix is a zero-element product), and the recurrence gives us $B_{1\times 1} = a_1$, so we're ok for the base case.

Rearranging the recurrence and using $a_0 = 1$ we get

$$B_{n\times n} = \sum_{i=1}^n (-1)^{i-1} a_i B_{(n-i)\times(n-i)}$$

Assuming our inductive hypothesis and substituting the definition of $a_i$, $$B_{n\times n} = (-1)^n \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{(2i-1)!!(2n-2i-3)!!}{(2i)!!(2n-2i)!!}$$

This is [Gosper-summable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gosper%27s_algorithm), with indefinite sum $$\sum_i \frac{(2i-1)!!(2n-2i-3)!!}{(2i)!!(2n-2i)!!} = \frac{i(2i-1)!!(2n-2i-1)!!}{n(2i)!!(2n-2i)!!}$$ so we get

$$\begin{eqnarray}
B_{n\times n} & = & (-1)^n \left[\frac{i(2i-1)!!(2n-2i-1)!!}{n(2i)!!(2n-2i)!!}\right]_1^{n+1} \\
 & = & (-1)^n \left[\frac{(n+1)(2n+1)!!(-3)!!}{n(2n+2)!!(-2)!!} - \frac{(1)!!(2n-3)!!}{n(2)!!(2n-2)!!}\right] \\
 & = & (-1)^{n-1} \frac{(2n-3)!!}{(2n)!!}
\end{eqnarray}
$$

as desired (where we use the fact that there's a pole at $(-2)!!$).

---

To close the loop on that generating function digression: $$f(z) = (1-z)^{-1/2} = 1 + \frac{\frac{1}{2} z}{1!} + \frac{\frac{1}{2} \frac{3}{2} z^2}{2!} + \dots = \sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{(2i-1)!! z^i}{2^i i!} = \sum_{i=0}^\infty a_i z^i$$

So the generating function for $B_{i\times i}$ is $\frac{1}{f(-z)}$ which agrees with my speculation, although it is more elegantly written as $g(z) = \frac{1}{f(-z)} = \sqrt{1+z}$.

---

#### Reference

[1] [On determinants of Toeplitz-Hessenberg matrices arising in power series](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022247X7890080X), Alfred Inselberg, Journal of Mathematical Analysis and Applications, Volume 63, Issue 2, April 1978, pp 347–353.

Comment: It's very very nice Thank you +1